# Git delete remote branches that are merged

Tags: git

I'm a little confused by the answers I see using:

```
git push -D
```

I'd like to delete all the branches returned from this result:

```
git branch -r --merged
```

Can't I simply combine them a la:

```
git push -D git branch -r --merged
```

Or is there a more elegant solution? And what about some query more complex that say deletes any unmerged branches without commits for the last 3 weeks? Here's my query for returning the list by commit date:

```
git branch -r --format="${commiterdate:iso8601},%commiterdate:relative)-%(refname.short)" --no-merged | sort
```

Comment: For a remote named `origin`, You might want to try `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=-1)" --merged=master refs/remotes/origin` to retrieve the list of remote branches merged in `master` (assuming `master`, you didn't mention "merged" *in what*), without the `origin/` prefix, then send that list into your push-delete command. (`git push --delete origin $(<the listing command here>)`). But be **sure** to have the list exactly right before you actually do the pushing.

Comment: (As a sidenote, you have 2 typos in your `format` (a `$` instead of `%` right at the begining of the format, then a bit further `refname.short` with a dot instead of the colon))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin with the second complex query:

> `git log --remotes --decorate-refs-exclude=tags/* --decorate-refs-exclude=heads/* --no-walk --before=3week --no-merges --pretty=%D | tr , '\n' | xargs -n1 git branch -r -D`

Why we begin with it? Because it includes both merged and non-merged branches with commits older than 3 weeks which you both want to delete. We could filter only non-merged branches here through `git branch -r --no-merged` but it doesn't make much sense for your particular task you want to achieve.

So here first we obtain last commits (`--no-walk`) older than 3 weeks (`--before=3week`) in remote branches (`--remotes`) and print decorated ref names (`--pretty=%D`). We filter out tags and local branches from the decorated refs with `--decorate-refs-exclude=tags/* --decorate-refs-exclude=heads/*`. Also we could probably want to skip merges (`--no-merges`) since they probably don't reflect actual work on branches.
So we get something like that:

```
origin/MH-7788
origin/mh-7852-2
origin/mh-7854-manchkin-edit, origin/manchkin-edit
origin/isua-delete
origin/MH-7811
origin/MH-7853
origin/widgets-delete
```

Then we split several refs in a line:

```
tr , '\n'
```

So we get our list of remote branches to delete:

```
origin/MH-7788
origin/mh-7852-2
origin/mh-7854-manchkin-edit
 origin/manchkin-edit
origin/isua-delete
origin/MH-7811
origin/MH-7853
origin/widgets-delete
```

Then we just use `xargs` to tell `git` to delete each branch (we don't care about space padding here, `xargs` trims them:

```
xargs -n1 git branch -r -D
```

So you deleted all remote branches (both merged and non-merged) with the last commit older than 3 weeks. Now just finish the job with deleting merged remotes:

```
git branch -r --merged | xargs -n1 git branch -r -D
```

---

### How to filter the log

Ok, the job is done but I've decided to delete **MERGED** branches older than 3 months. First I want to get a list of them with the commit date and the commiter:

> `comm -12 <(git log --remotes --decorate-refs-exclude=tags/* --decorate-refs-exclude=heads/* --no-walk --no-merges --before=3month --pretty=%D | tr , '\n'  | xargs -n1 | sort) <(git branch -r --merged | xargs -n1 | sort) | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} | tr '\n' '|'; git --no-pager log -1 --no-merges --pretty='%cd|%cN' {}" | sort -k2 -r -t "|" | column -t -s "|"`

Here I compare our first query with `git branch -r --merged` to get common lines that would match the both queries. Then I do some double job unfortunately and ask git for log again for each branch but now it's formatted. I want to prefix a log line with the branch name so I `echo` a branch with a new line deletion. Since the whole line is printed inside a separate shell we have a git pager interfering (I have `less`) so we should ask git not to use the pager. I have `|` delimited fields as a result. First I `sort` by the date column then print as a table with `column`.

As a result I get:

```
origin/mh-7724-reverts      2023-02-28  Natalia Baganova
origin/top-btn              2023-02-21  zayceva
origin/MH-7718              2023-02-16  George Barlukov
origin/MH-7667              2023-02-07  George Barlukov
origin/MH-7689              2023-02-01  George Barlukov
origin/MH-7398-v3           2023-01-26  George Barlukov
origin/MH-7398-v2           2023-01-23  George Barlukov
origin/MH-7596              2023-01-19  George
origin/email-popup          2023-01-18  George
origin/FR-1016              2022-12-26  Dilya
origin/FR-995_kaz-cdek      2022-12-20  over_ilaj
```

Now when I examined the report I can delete the branches:

> `comm -12 <(git log --remotes --decorate-refs-exclude=tags/* --decorate-refs-exclude=heads/* --no-walk --no-merges --before=3month --pretty=%D | tr , '\n'  | xargs -n1 | sort) <(git branch -r --merged | xargs -n1 | sort) | xargs -n1 git branch -r -D`

```
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-1016 (was de5b5f618).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-120_regions (was 5432cc4f5).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-192_gmaps2 (was 08b31703b).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-194_kiev_maps (was f67ba0240).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-199_logout (was 2b8c28939).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-224_bags (was f61d180d8).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-993-1 (was c259a2dfa).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-994_kazpost (was 701e3544e).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/FR-995_kaz-cdek (was 1dda904fc).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/MH-7292-fix (was 383dade6b).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/MH-7398-v2 (was d638591e7).
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/MH-7398-v3 (was c68b976a8).
```

Comment: @fumeng you are welcome. actually thank you since i'm learning git right now and you helped me a lot to exercise. but we have some problem. seems `git branch -r -D` doesn't work since after `git fetch` i got the deleted remote branches again. i'll investigate the problem and return back to you with an update to my answer and add here a comment when it's done. stay tuned!

Comment: Remote-tracking branches are not meant to be created/deleted by hand. They're updated when you fetch, and you can prune them with `-p` to reflect deleted remote branches. Just delete remote branches with some version of `git push` then your (local) remote-tracking branches will be ready for the pruning.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I can relate, that's also how I learned 80% of what I know about git. SO is the best school! :-)

Comment: Have you figured out any easy way to delete the remote branches in bulk? I have ended up generating `git push origin :refs/heads/branch-name` from the list I've obtained using your query above. And then running it in the cli. Quite slow and manual, but still better than doing it by hand.

Comment: @Vočko git push origin -d branch-name

Comment: Yep, that's doing the same thing but doesn't solve the problem of bulk delete.